# Bias-variance: is it really a "trade-off"?

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

For some estimator $\hat{\theta}$, we have the "bias-variance trade-off": $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = bias^2(\hat{\theta}) + var(\hat{\theta}).$

When I think of a trade-off, I would expect that as the variance goes down, the squared bias would go up, and vice versa. But I'm not sure this is the case here, since $MSE(\hat{\theta})$ is not fixed as $\hat{\theta}$ as varies.

**Example**:
Consider two silly estimates for the mean of a single normally distributed data point $x \sim N(\theta, 1)$:
$\delta_0(x) = 0$ and $\delta_1(x) = 1$. Both of these has the same variance of $0$. Furthermore, $bias^2(\delta_0) = \theta^2$ and $bias^2(\delta_1) = (1-\theta)^2$. Therefore, both estimators have the same bias but different squared biases (assuming $\theta \ne \frac{1}{2}$).

So in what sense is there a trade-off here?

Comment: The bias-variance tradeoff is a "rule of thumb" and not a law. No one claimed it was a law.

Comment: @JakeWestfall could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jake Isn't the concept of a "minimum variance unbiased estimator" tantamount to such a law?  Its very existence shows that if one can find any estimator (in the same family) with lower variance, it must increase the bias above zero, right?  Qman: Your $\delta_i$ are not written like estimators.  Estimators are functions of the *data*, not of the parameter.  It isn't at all clear how you are computing the "bias" or even what you might mean by it.

Comment: Right. I think the $\delta$'s should be functions of $x$, not $\theta$.

Comment: It's possible for an estimator to be dominated by another in both bias and variance simultaneously. This doesn't contradict the fact that there is a trade-off between those that are on the "boundary" of the feasible set in bias-variance space (the ones that achieve the lowest variance for a fixed level of bias, like MVUE).

Comment: "*both estimators have the same bias*" ... they don't. Do you mean to say "variance" there?

Answer (score 3):

I share your skepticism that there is a tradeoff. A typical way to think about the bias-variance decomposition of MSE, such as in regularized regression, is that we accept a bit of bias in our estimator in exchange for a large reduction in variance. However, we do this to achieve lower MSE, not to maintain the MSE. Thus, while I understand the "trade" being used to describe trading your unbiased, high variance estimator for a slightly biased, low variance estimator, "tradeoff" to me implies keeping MSE constant, and I try not to describe it as a "tradeoff", preferring to refer to a bias-variance "decomposition".