# Practical usage of the bias variance tradeoff

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, bias-variance-tradeoff

I understand the bias-variance tradeoff. But, I have never come across a scenario where that has changed anything in the modelling process. Is there any practical scenario that you have encountered where you dug into the bias and the variance tradeoff and the way you proceeded with the modeling changed because of that?

I have been through scenarios where I have had models that had pretty different performances on different validation sets (in cross-validation) and then I reduced the model complexity as a consequence of that but that is just dealing with the observation that "maybe the model is too complex". But, I have not had any scenario where the tradeoff between bias or variance or that knowledge came in handy and led to an actual action.

Comment: The main motivation for *tuning* a model is to find a good bias-variance tradeoff. This obviously has a direct impact on the final model, even if you do not explicitly quantify the bias and the variance.

Comment: "I have had pretty different performances on different validation sets... and then I reduced the model complexity". That basically *is* the bias-variance tradeoff. You found an overfit model with low bias but high variance, and based on that observation, decided to use a less overfit model that probably performed worse on the training data (higher bias) but better on the test data (lower variance). Anytime you're evaluating train/test performance, you are implicitly evaluating model bias/variance.

Comment: The bias variance tradeoff is the sea in which model selection swims.  Any time you choose a model, whether it's the type of model (tree? OLS? MARS?), the number of variables, the types of transformation etc., you are using the bias variance tradeoff.

Comment: [It might be helpful not to think of it as a “tradeoff”. To me, such a term implies that the mean squared error is held constant while the bias and variance change, when the goal of, say, regularization, is to increase the bias only a little bit so that the large reduction in variance leads to a smaller, not equal, mean squared error.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/611164/247274)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491501/is-the-idea-of-a-bias-variance-tradeoff-a-false-construct?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

"Although the bias-variance decomposition may provide some interesting insights into the model complexity issue from a frequentist perspective, it is of limited practical value, because the bias-variance decomposition is based on averages
with respect to ensembles of data sets, whereas in practice we have only the single
observed data set. If we had a large number of independent training sets of a given
size, we would be better off combining them into a single large training set, which
of course would reduce the level of over-fitting for a given model complexity." - *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* (Bishop).